# In which OS that Java runs on is "\n" not a valid newline sequence?

Tags: java

I know Java recommends the use of `line.separator` for `\n` newline because some operating systems may not necessarily recognize `\n`. What operating systems are these?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html

Comment: I am surprise (and pleased) you haven't used Windows more. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On Windows, `\r\n` is the newline sequence.

The original Mac OS (but not OS X) uses `\r`.

Comment: Thanks Taymon. Can i also say that because Mac OS uses \r, it does not recognize \n? When you say its \r\n on Windows, \n works too, am i missing something? Thanks.

Comment: Some Windows programs may be able to detect Unix-style newlines and deal with them correctly, but not all. Try saving a text file under Unix and then opening it in Windows Notepad; it won't realize that the `\n`s in the document are supposed to be newlines, so it will display the entire document in one very long line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that Java translates the \n into the appropriate newline character for the OS you are using, thus making your job as a programmer easier.

----  EDIT ----

As it turns out what I wrote above might be incorrect, although I believe it is correct for certain scenarios e.g. within UI controls etc.  But here are two methods on two different classes you can use to write the OS-appropriate newline character(s) to a file, rather than trying to manage it yourself:

[PrintWriter.println()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println%28%29)

and

[BufferedWriter.newLine()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine%28%29)

Comment: Do you know where it says that in the docs? You may be right, but I can't find anything that says that (and the existence of the `%n` sequence in `String.format` suggests that `\n` isn't portable).

Comment: Hi Taymon, please see my edit above, I hope these methods are helpful for you.

Comment: What actually happens is that readLine() recognizes either \r\n or \r or \n as the newline separator; removes it; and then the UI control adds the content of line.separator. There is no actual 'translation' happening.